# Angularjs click multiple button

Tags: angularjs, button, click

i have a problem with button click with angular.
i have create the buttons in a js page and in another page i have write the function for each button.
My problem is when I click one button the program dont run the associate function.
Can you help me please? thanks

this is the code

button code

```
replay=document.createElement('div');
replay.style.position='absolute';
replay.style.top = '10%';
replay.style.width = '30px;';
replay.style.left='10px;';
replay.innerHTML = "<button ng-click='clearReplay()'> Clear&nbsp </button><button ng-click='btnStop()'>&nbspStop&nbsp</button><button class='alert' ng-click='btnON()'> OnRec </button><button class='success' ng-click='btnOFF()'> OffRec </button><button ng-click='history()'>History</button>";
container.appendChild( replay );
```

this is code of the function:

```
'use strict'


angular.module('cubeApp', [])
.controller('controller', ['$scope',
    function($scope){


$scope.clearReplay=function(){
            alert("ciaooo");
            insideText='';
            various.innerHTML = insideText;
            replayCounter=0;
            socket.emit('clearReplays');

}


$scope.btnStop=function(){          
            socket.emit("stopReplay");

}

$scope.btnON=function(){
//inizio a registrare

            registering = true;
            rotation.innerHTML = "registering..."
            socket.emit("startRec");

}

$scope.btnOFF=function(){
//stoppa la registrazione dei data 
            rotation.innerHTML = ""
            socket.emit("stopRec");
            if(replayCounter<5 && registering == true){
                replayCounter++;
                registering = false;
                insideText=insideText + "<button id='btnStart" + replayCounter + "'>"+replayCounter+"</button>";
                various.innerHTML = insideText;             
            }else{console.log("replay limit");}
          }


$scope.toggle=function(){
// passo da rad a gradi e viceversa
            BarValue[0]=0;
            BarValue[1]=0;
            if(barStyle=='rad'){
                barStyle='gradi';

            }
            else {
                barStyle='rad';
            }

 }

$scope.runtime=function(){
            //stoppo l esecuzione del runtime dei grafici
            if(stopRuntime==false){stopRuntime=true;}
            else{stopRuntime=false;}

}

$scope.history=function(){
            //stoppo l esecuzione del runtime dei grafici
            if(stopHistory==false){stopHistory=true;}
            else{stopHistory=false;}

}


 }
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple problem, you create the DOM on the fly without angularjs knowing it, so it really doesn't keep track of ng-click, you should abandon idea of manipulating view outside angularjs since it MVC and view should be driven by controller